# How to check if a post is in two given categories

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I have category named news and featured post. I want to show if the post is both in news and featured-post.

```
$args = array('category_name' => 'news','featured-post','posts_per_page'=>1);

$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help you out with using `get_posts`.

However you may try it with `WP_Query`as stated in [wordpress' documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) under `Display posts that have "all" of these categories:`

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'category_name=news+featured-post' );
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $my_query->have_posts() ):
    $my_query->the_post();
    //do things with the post
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to `get_posts` you can use `WP_Query` with `category__and` (note the double underscore!) to return posts which are placed in two (or more) categories.

```
$args = array('category__and' => array(1, 2));
$result = new WP_Query($args);
while($result->have_posts())
{
   // do whatever you want
}
```